# Git Home Page missing icons in VS 2017 15.2 (26430.13)

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I've found this [website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/work-team-explorer) which explains on how you can access work items and other stuff from Visual Studio if you're using Team Services.

We're using Team Services, but my Home screen looks different/is missing a couple of key options. Also when creating a commit, I'm not able to link work items as suggested [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/02/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/) in section "Linking to existing artifacts".

Can anyone help me on what I might be doing wrong?

[image: Home screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that, then you are just using a Git repository, without being linked to the Team Services. When you connect to Team Services (or TFS), you automatically get the Git repository stuff (assuming you are using Git), but the reverse is not true since Visual Studio allows you to use any Git repository whether it has a related TFS project or not.

In order to get access to the Team Services, you need to connect your project to the server. You can do that from that little green plug icon in the Team Explorer’s toolbar. From there, choose “Manage Connections” to find the Team Services project and the repository you want to connect with.

Comment: When I connect to Team Services via green plug icon I'm connected to TFVC and I can only choose TFVC projects. Other git repositorys can't be found from that option (at least i'm not good enough to find this option)

Comment: I figured out which part I was missing. Mabye you can edit your reply in order to emphasize it. "you need to connect your project to the server" was throwing me off. "You need to connection to your repository through Manage Connections" would have directed me better. I hope you know what I mean. Project is a word i've been exclusively using with TFVC while Repository is what Git uses.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry about that, I didn’t have a VS open at the time, so I couldn’t check how the dialogs look after clicking the plug icon (I knew there was more, but couldn’t remember). I’ve added instructions now to make it hopefully more clear.